# JQuery Traversing through DOM on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having problem of traversing through each HTML element one by one.There are two buttons `#up` and `#down`.On click of `#up` the id `#myID` should move to the next element upwards and vice versa for `#down`.The problem is I am able to move through the siblings but not through the child elements.

For example if I click on `#down` the id `#myID` should have moved to `p` tag which is the child of that `div` on next click to `span` which is child of `p` then on next click to `div`.But in my code it is directly jumping to `div` ignoring the children.

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/h6rag2x4/1/)**

Here is the code:

```js
$("#up").click(function() {
  $("#startHere").find("#myID").next().attr('id', 'myID');
  $('#startHere').find("#myID").removeAttr('id');
});
$("#down").click(function() {
  $("#startHere").find("#myID").prev().attr('id', 'myID');
  $('#startHere').find("#myID").next().removeAttr('id');
})
```

```css
#myID {
  border: 2px solid yellow;
}

#startHere {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
}

div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid;
  margin: 10px;
}

p {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  margin: 10px;
}

h1 {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: 10px;
}

span {
  display: block;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  border: 2px solid green;
  margin: 10px;
}

button {
  height: 25px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="up">GO DOWN</button>
<button id="down">GO UP</button>
<div id="startHere">
  <div id="myID">
    <p><span></span></p>
  </div>
  <div><span></span></div>
  <div>
    <h1></h1>
  </div>
  <p></p>
  <h1></h1>
  <p><span></span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: You've to work with `children()` function... `.next()` just takes the next element on the same level

Comment: @Nitro.de Yes that is the problem because I am not able to find how many children are there for each element and how to target them one at a time.

Comment: You can check with `$("#myID").children().length` if length === 0 there're no children else you can use `$("#myID").children().first()` to select the first child

Comment: @Nitro.de even I was trying something like that but was unable to do it can you provide a demo code.

Comment: In my original code its by using class this is just a sample fiddle.

Comment: So what are the rules? If choice is to go to sibling or children which takes precedence? And how do you prevent going to children when you really want to go down in siblings?

Comment: @charlietfl first the children then the next sibling

Comment: So from last child jump to parent sibling?

Comment: @charlietfl Yes, then to the next sibling

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can just find all the elements first, jQuery returns them in DOM order, which is what you want. No need to search for the next/prev element on-the-fly.

```
var allElements = $("#startHere").find('*');
var currentIndex = allElements.index('#myID');

function move(delta) {
    // Find the new index
    var index = currentIndex + delta;
    // Clamp to 0…lengh of list
    // Here we could also make it wrap instead
    index = Math.max(Math.min(index, allElements.length - 1), 0);
    // Remove the ID from the old element
    allElements.eq(currentIndex).removeAttr('id');
    // Add the ID to the new element
    allElements.eq(index).attr('id', 'myID');
    // Update the index
    currentIndex = index;
}

$("#up").click(function() {
  move(1);
});
$("#down").click(function() {
  move(-1);
})
```

```js
var allElements = $("#startHere").find('*');
var currentIndex = allElements.index('#myID');

function move(delta) {
    // Find the new index
    var index = currentIndex + delta;
    // Clamp to 0…lengh of list
    // Here we could also make it wrap instead
    index = Math.max(Math.min(index, allElements.length - 1), 0);
    // Remove the ID from the old element
    allElements.eq(currentIndex).removeAttr('id');
    // Add the ID to the new element
    allElements.eq(index).attr('id', 'myID');
    // Update the index
    currentIndex = index;
}

$("#up").click(function() {
  move(-1);
});
$("#down").click(function() {
  move(1);
})
```

```css
#myID {
  border: 2px solid yellow;
}

#startHere {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
}

div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid;
  margin: 10px;
}

p {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  margin: 10px;
}

h1 {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: 10px;
}

span {
  display: block;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  border: 2px solid green;
  margin: 10px;
}

button {
  height: 25px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="down">GO DOWN</button>
<button id="up">GO UP</button>
<div id="startHere">
  <div id="myID">
    <p><span></span></p>
  </div>
  <div><span></span></div>
  <div>
    <h1></h1>
  </div>
  <p></p>
  <h1></h1>
  <p><span></span></p>
</div>
```

If you do need the elements on-the-fly (because they might have changed), you can still use the same tactic (and simply build up the `allElements` list in the `move` function and get the index using `allElements.index('#myID')`) but it might be more performant to update the list only when you know it changed (after an Ajax request, after modification on event handlers, etc.).

*Edit:*

The code for searching the next/prev element on-the-fly is a bit more work because it has to recurse when traversing up but makes it possible to have a different set of rules for up vs. down movement.

```
var boundary = $("#startHere");

function findNext(node, anchor) {
  if(!anchor && node.children(':first-child').length) {
    return node.children(':first-child');
  }
  if(node.next().length) {
    return node.next();
  }
  if(!boundary.find(node.parent()).length) {
    // Out of boundary. Stick to the last node
    return anchor||node;
  }
  return findNext(node.parent(), anchor||node);
}

function findPrev(node, anchor) {
  if(!anchor && node.children(':last-child').length) {
    return node.children(':last-child');
  }
  if(node.prev().length) {
    return node.prev();
  }
  if(!boundary.find(node.parent()).length) {
    // Out of boundary. Stick to the last node
    return anchor||node;
  }
  return findPrev(node.parent(), anchor||node);
}

function move(finder) {
  // Find the current item
  var current = boundary.find('#myID');
  // Find the next item
  var next = finder(current);
  // Remove the ID from the old element
  current.removeAttr('id');
  // Add the ID to the new element
  next.attr('id', 'myID');
}

$("#up").click(function() {
  move(findPrev);
});
$("#down").click(function() {
  move(findNext);
})
```

```js
var boundary = $("#startHere");

function findNext(node, anchor) {
  if(!anchor && node.children(':first-child').length) {
    return node.children(':first-child');
  }
  if(node.next().length) {
    return node.next();
  }
  if(!boundary.find(node.parent()).length) {
    // Out of boundary. Stick to the last node
    return anchor||node;
  }
  return findNext(node.parent(), anchor||node);
}

function findPrev(node, anchor) {
  if(!anchor && node.children(':last-child').length) {
    return node.children(':last-child');
  }
  if(node.prev().length) {
    return node.prev();
  }
  if(!boundary.find(node.parent()).length) {
    // Out of boundary. Stick to the last node
    return anchor||node;
  }
  return findPrev(node.parent(), anchor||node);
}

function move(finder) {
  // Find the current item
  var current = boundary.find('#myID');
  // Find the next item
  var next = finder(current);
  // Remove the ID from the old element
  current.removeAttr('id');
  // Add the ID to the new element
  next.attr('id', 'myID');
}

$("#up").click(function() {
  move(findPrev);
});
$("#down").click(function() {
  move(findNext);
})
```

```css
#myID {
  border: 2px solid yellow;
}

#startHere {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
}

div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid;
  margin: 10px;
}

p {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  margin: 10px;
}

h1 {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: 10px;
}

span {
  display: block;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  border: 2px solid green;
  margin: 10px;
}

button {
  height: 25px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="down">GO DOWN</button>
<button id="up">GO UP</button>
<div id="startHere">
  <div id="myID">
    <p><span></span></p>
  </div>
  <div><span></span></div>
  <div>
    <h1></h1>
  </div>
  <p></p>
  <h1></h1>
  <p><span></span></p>
</div>
```

This is really bad UI. To select some nodes in some states, you first have to navigate “UP” and then “DOWN” again. But it seems to do what you ask for.

Comment: Its is working perfectly for #down but for #up it should be first the sibling then the child.

Comment: its very superb one

Comment: @shubhamagrawal So the order for “up” should not be = reverse(the order for “down”)?

Comment: @RaphaelSchweikert yes

Comment: @shubhamagrawal when doing 'up' you can pass the number of children instead of  -1 hardcoded.

Comment: @shubhamagrawal I think that makes for a bad UI experience: think about what happens when we press “up” on a selected item that has children vs. when we press “down”. You’d expect only one of these actions to descend into the children but in fact, both will (up will select the last child, down will select the first child). Usually pressing up and then down (or the other way around) is expected to result in the same element being selected as initially but in your case, it won’t.
I’ll try to come up with a solution that does what you want, though.

Comment: @RaphaelSchweikert I kind of realized that but that's the project requirement.

Comment: @RaphaelSchweikert it works except first and last but this will help me do what I want to achieve. Thanks for the solution.